# saving audio buffers from callback function

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

In my audio input callback function on the iPhone  i am getting a 1024 samples buffers.
I need to save them for about 3 seconds of input sounds . it means that each buffer is 23ms so more or less 50 buffers for each second, so i am having this array :

```
int16_t buffersRing[200][1025];
```

which each callback is filled with data :

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData)
{


    AudioBuffer buffer;
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2; //* sizeof(SInt16) ?
    buffer.mData = NULL; 

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;
    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit,
                             ioActionFlags,
                             inTimeStamp,
                             inBusNumber,
                             inNumberFrames,
                             &bufferList);


    int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;

buffersRing[ringNum][0]=inNumberFrames;
         for( int k=1;k<inNumberFrames+1;k++)
             buffersRing[ringNum][k]=q[k-1];
```

I can see it takes so much memory somehow. (the array) , and i think also too much time to fill them.
I wonder if there is a better way to save ALL buffers of a 3-4 seconds so i can process them later on .
Thanks .

Comment: First I suggest using memcpy, it should be faster than a for loop.
Second, you can reduce the sampling rate, and store less data.

Comment: thanks, i cant reduce sampling , my nyquist should be high. how do i use memcpy?